# log4net not logging in try catch

Tags: vb.net, web-services, log4net

I have a Try Catch in my web service method, the test code I've put in the try does get hit and logs correctly. The logging code in my catch gets hit by the debugger but nothing gets logged, is there a reason for this? I'm thinking it may just be the 'nature of the beast' so to speak, where it shuts down execution of the page when hitting the catch maybe?

Code below:

```
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports log4net

<System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<ToolboxItem(False)> _

Public Class LendingService
Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService


Private Shared ReadOnly log As log4net.ILog = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType)


<WebMethod()> _
Public Function ApplicantCreate() As String

    Try
        'This logs
        log.Info("Testing Of LendingService")

        'Throwing exception for testing purposes
        Throw New NullReferenceException

    Catch ex As Exception
        'This does not log
        log.Error("Error creating applicant: " & Server.GetLastError.Message)
        'Eventually we will log errors here (same for all other methods below)
        'Return "Test"
    End Try
End Function

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out what the problem was, the following line was causing some wonky behaviour :

```
log.Error("Error creating applicant: " & Server.GetLastError.Message)
```

It would take me into the backend .net code for the error handling, once I changed it to this:

```
log.Error("Error creating applicant: " & ex.Message)
```

It worked correctly and I now see a log entry for the error.